# Combinations of values in each cell in a symmetric matrix

Tags: r, matrix, symmetric

I have a vector of weights that I want to  insert in a symmetric matrix. I want all combinations of weights (all weights in all positions but not in the diagonal)

I tried iterating through the matrix, but then I only get the same matrix triplicate. (Also I couldn't find it answered or a public solution to this problem.)

```
weight <- seq(0.1, 1, by = 0.1)
C <- matrix(0, nrow = 3, ncol = 3)
for (i in seq_len(nrow(C))) {
  C_old <- C
  for (j in seq_len(i)) {
    if (i == j) {
      C[i, i] <- 0
    } else {
      C_old2 <- C_old
      for (w in weight) {
        C[i, j] <- w
        C[j, i] <- C[i, j]
        C_old[i, j] <- w
        C_old[j, i] <- C_old[i, j]
        C_old2[i, j] <- w
        C_old2[j, i] <- C_old2[i, j]
        iter <- iter + 3
        print(C)
        print(C_old)
        print(C_old2)
      }
   }
}
```

I want to have all the matrices such that

```
Matrix 0:

0 0 0
0 0 0
0 0 0 


Matrix 1:

0 0 0
0 0 0.1
0 0.1 0 

Matrix 2:

0 0 0.1
0 0 0.1
0.1 0.1 0 


Matrix 3:

0 0.1 0.1
0.1 0 0.1
0.1 0.1 0 

Matrix 4:

0 0.1 0.1
0.1 0 0.2
0.1 0.2 0 


Matrix n:

0 0.9 0.1
0.5 0 0.5
0.1 0.9 0 


Matrix:

0 x y
z 0 z
y x 0
```

I want all combinations of the last matrix were x, y and z can be any value in weight.

The first matrix (all 0) is not really important, so if a solution omits it I don't really care

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to LAP I changed the approach and I managed how to do this:

```
weight <- seq(0.1, 1, by = 0.1)
C <- matrix(0, nrow = 3, ncol = 3)
C_list <- vector("list", 10)
names(C_list) <- as.character(weight)

for(i1 in weight){
  C_list[[as.character(i1)]] <- vector("list", 10)
  names(C_list[[as.character(i1)]]) <- as.character(weight)
  for (i2 in weight){
    C_list[[as.character(i1)]][[as.character(i2)]] <- vector("list", 10)
    names(C_list[[as.character(i1)]][[as.character(i2)]]) <- as.character(weight)
    for (i3 in weight) {
      C[2, 3] <- i1
      C[3, 2] <- i1
      C[1, 3] <- i2
      C[3, 1] <- i2
      C[1, 2] <- i3
      C[2, 1] <- i3
      C_list[[as.character(i1)]][[as.character(i2)]][[as.character(i3)]] <- C
    }
  }
}
```

Now the C_list is a list of lists of lists that each one has a matrix. `length(unlist(unlist(C_list, recursive = FALSE), recursive = FALSE)) == 1000` that are the 10^3 combinations that exists.

Comment: Thanks for you time and idea I hope I can now somehow extend to more positions but this is better than nothing. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

No idea what you want this for, but here you go:

```
weight <- seq(0.1, 1, by = 0.1)
C <- matrix(0, nrow = 3, ncol = 3)
C_list <- vector("list", 10)

for(i in 1:length(weight)){
  for(j in 1:3){
    if(j == 1){
      C[2,3] <- weight[i]
      C[3,2] <- weight[i]
    }
    if(j == 2){
      C[1,3] <- weight[i]
      C[3,1] <- weight[i]
    }
    if(j == 3){
      C[1,2] <- weight[i]
      C[2,1] <- weight[i]
    }
    C_list[[i]][[j]] <- C
  }
}
```

Result:

```
> C_list
[[1]]
[[1]][[1]]
     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]    0  0.0  0.0
[2,]    0  0.0  0.1
[3,]    0  0.1  0.0

[[1]][[2]]
     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]  0.0  0.0  0.1
[2,]  0.0  0.0  0.1
[3,]  0.1  0.1  0.0

[[1]][[3]]
     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]  0.0  0.1  0.1
[2,]  0.1  0.0  0.1
[3,]  0.1  0.1  0.0


[[2]]
[[2]][[1]]
     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]  0.0  0.1  0.1
[2,]  0.1  0.0  0.2
[3,]  0.1  0.2  0.0

[[2]][[2]]
     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]  0.0  0.1  0.2
[2,]  0.1  0.0  0.2
[3,]  0.2  0.2  0.0
```

...

Comment: I'll edit my question because I won't have explained well. I want all combinations, so I might have a 0.8, with a 0.2 and a 0.5 cell value in the same matrix. BTW this is for a model I use to analyse some data. I am trying to find the optimum value for this parameter.